# iOS - How often to check keychain credentials

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios6

After validating and storing a users credentials in the keychain, how often do I need to check if they are still there or still valid?  Should I call a method on each ViewDidAppear and check if they are bad or don't exist then show the login modal?

Answer (score 1):

**Note** : Once you stored users credentials in the keychain successfully then keyChain credentials `persist after your app is deleted`. So need to worry about checking if they are still there or still valid

Also don't forget remove users credentials from the keychain before application gets uninstalled

Refer [keychain demo](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html) link.